# Android: Wait for userinput but set a timeout

Tags: android, android-fragments, countdowntimer, futuretask, busy-waiting

In my application the user is prompted with an exercise and he has 5 seconds to solve it, if he does not respond in time, the next exercise should be shown.
My question is: **What would be the best way to implement such a behaviour in Android?**

I have first tried it with a `CountDownTimer` but for some reason the `CountDownTimer.cancel()` does not cancel the timer.

My second attempt works, (see below) but it contains a buisy wait and I don't know if that is such a good pattern.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EXERCISES; i++) {
    // show a new fragment with an activity

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.exercise_container, getNextExercise())
            .commit();

    // I create a thread and let it sleep for 5 seconds, and then I wait busily
    // until either the thread is done or the user answers and I call future.cancel()
    // in the method that is responsible for handling the userinput

    future = es.submit(()->{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return null;
    });

    while (!future.isDone()) { }
}
```

It works like this: I create a Java Future which task it is to just wait 5 seconds and in the callback method, that is responsible for handling the userinput I call `future.cancel()`, so the `while` loop can be left and the code gets executed further, meaning the for loop does another iteration.
If the user does not respond in time, the `while` loop is left after 5 seconds, ensuring that the user does not spend too much time on one exercise.

Feel free to ask for further clarification if needed. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The timer should be canceled in your code. try this :

```
        private var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() {}

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            Log.d("millisUntil", millisUntilFinished.toString())
            if ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) <= 5) {
                countDownTimer?.cancel()
            }
        }
    }.start()
```

It is a 10sec timer and it cancels at 5sec by calling `countDownTimer?.cancel()`.

Comment: the timer would be a perfect choice for the usage you described.

Comment: "The timer should be canceled in your code." What do you mean by that? Furthermore, I cannot cancel the timer in the `onTick()` method, I have to cancel the timer in the callback method that is handling the userinput. But, for some reason, that doesn't work.

Comment: This is just an example. you can cancel it outside the onTick method as well. For more control, you can put a counter inside a view model and observe it so you will know when it stops. inside the observer navigate to another fragment.

Comment: The problem is, that the `CountDownTimer` *needs* to be canceled from the same thread as it has started. If I try to call `CountDownTimer.cancel()` from another thread, it doesn't work. If I call the `CountDownTimer` from the main thread, I don't have some kind of `await()` method, so how do I wait for the CDTimer to finish? The `for` loop would immediately go into  another iteration, replacing the current exercise. On the other hand, if I create a thread executing the `CountDownTimer.start()` method, it does not terminate after the timer is at 0.